# Какой знак препинания нужно использовать в диалоге?

Tags: пунктуация, диалог

На днях состоялась переписка, по одной из частей которой возник спор относительно верного знака препинания.

Для примера приведу сам диалог:

```
- Привет, это Женя - добавь ее в контакты.
- Кто такой Женя?
- Менеджер (?) ты с ним общался.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой здесь (в скобках) нужен знак препинания: двоеточие или тире? Как можно обосновать, почему именно тот, а не иной знак препинания необходимо использовать в приведенном примере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не двоеточие, а тире или запятая, вполне по-русски (как и уже предложенная точка). Не двоеточие, потому что вторая часть — это *не раскрытие первой*.

Answer (score 2):

> Какой знак препинания стоит использовать в диалоге?

Я бы поставил **точку.**

Comment: Точка с запятой тоже могла бы подойти...

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, на каком основании предлагают двоеточие, если стоит тире?! Действительно, ни двоеточие, ни, тем более, тире, здесь не уместны. Одно тире уже стоит, второе тире не нужно, это диалог. Двоеточие раскрывает, поясняет смысл предыдущего предложения, слова.
Здесь вполне органична точка.

Answer (score 1):

Да и запятая вполне подходит. Боитесь, что можно принять за обращение? Я бы не боялся, из контекста же все понятно.

Comment: Конечно, и запятая вполне органична.